# Getting Black screen as splash screen on flutter app startup

Tags: android, flutter, splash-screen

My **AndroidManifest.xml :**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.flutter_application_1">
   <application
        android:label="flutter_application_1"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My **launch_background.xml :**(*I have given white color but still getting black screen*)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </item> 
</layer-list>
```

My **style.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
       <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
       <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**res** folder :

[image]

**flutter run --verbose :** (*Report*)
[Verbose Report](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DlckRernv3NKGApBt43ETBkYO0CSW3dt/view?usp=sharing)

Remaining everything is working fine, the only problem that I am facing is with this Launch/Splash Screen.
Please help me out to figure it out.

Comment: Same here, did you solve your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your **styles.xml** file, it should look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
  
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

If still no result, try to use `<item>` attribute instead `<bitmap>` for **launch_image** inside **launch_background.xml**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/launch_image"
        android:gravity="center" />
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but still there is no change, I have updated my question by including my "style.xml" file plus the "res" folder screen short.